# Return all tuesdays in 2018 for every other column

Tags: google-sheets

In E2 I got this code:

```
=transpose(query(ArrayFormula(date(2018, 1, 1)+row(E2:365)-1), "select Col1 where DAYOFWEEK(Col1) matches '3' "))
```

which returns all dates of Tuesdays in 2018 in the next columns.

Can someone help modify this to only insert for every other column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=if(column()=5,date(2018,1,2),if(iseven(column()),"",$E2+7*int((column()-5)/2)))
```

and copy it across as far as required.